# Build rules for Swift source files

Tags: swift, xcode, build, compilation

Xcode supports custom [`Build Rules`](https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/build-process/#build-rules) for different source files. I am particularly interested in Swift build rule.

What should be correct script to compile the sources and what to specify in `Output Files`?

Please, answer the question if you did have experience with that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift files are compiled with *swiftc* implicitly, as well as Obj-C with *clang*. Afaik it's not possible to substitute that call with a Build Rule, as you also would need to pass tons of arguments for the optimizer, libraries for linker e.t.c. The output of source code compilation is object files (*.o), which are then linked together to form a resulting binary.

You can read about this process [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/compiler/) and [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/mach-o-executables/).